# How do I determine what prompts systemd to restart an unwanted process?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, mate, dbus, gnome-screensaver

I've installed Mate on top of Unity in Ubuntu 16.04. In my process list, `gnome-screensaver` appears persistently with `systemd` as its PPID:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username  8434     1  0 09:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
```

I can kill it, but closing and reopening the laptop causes it to start again.

The service responsible is `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.ScreenSaver.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.ScreenSaver
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
```

So, it looks like some `dbus` event related to closing and reopening the laptop is what's causing the continual restart.

How can I determine what file or setting it is that causes `gnome-screensaver` to restart?

Comment: to disable would be `sudo systemctl disable org.gnome.ScreenSaver`, for the reason, post the complete service file.

Comment: @George Thanks for the tip, but that command gives `Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory` (adding the absolute path to the file doesn't help).  And that is the complete service file.